# How make `this` in a scope to refer to Kotlin Android Extension type class?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a code as below

```
        recycler_view.apply {
            // Some other code
            LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(this)   
        }
```

In case I would like to use `apply`, the below `this` is error out

```
        recycler_view.apply {
            // Some other code
            LinearSnapHelper().apply {
                  .attachToRecyclerView(this) // This will error because `this` is LinearSnapHelper()
            }
        }
```

I tried `this@RecyclerView` still error

```
        recycler_view.apply {
            // Some other code
            LinearSnapHelper().apply {
                  .attachToRecyclerView(this@RecyclerView) // Still error
            }
        }
```

I tried `this@recycler_view` still error

```
        recycler_view.apply {
            // Some other code
            LinearSnapHelper().apply {
                  .attachToRecyclerView(this@recycler_view) // Still error
            }
        }
```

What's the syntax to refer to the `this` to `recycler_view`?

Note: I can do the below, but just like to learn how to have how we could have `this` in the `apply` refers to Kotlin Android Extension type class.

```
        recycler_view.apply {
            // Some other code
            LinearSnapHelper().apply {
                // Some other code
            }.attachToRecyclerView(this)
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can apply explicit label to outer lambda:

```
recycler_view.apply recycler@{
    // Some other code
    LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(this@recycler)   
}
```

However nesting `apply` blocks doesn't look idiomatic and can be confusing, I'd suggest using other scoping function for `recycler_view` like `let`:

```
recycler_view.let { recycler ->
    // Some other code
    LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recycler)   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own scope actually, like this.

```
recycler_view.apply myCustomScope@ {
      // Some other code
      LinearSnapHelper().apply {
          attachToRecyclerView(this@myCustomScope)
      }
}
```